# Build scripts driven from yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to run a build scripts framework, so build scripts can be configured via yaml file `tasks.yml`:

```
---
release:  # This is a 'runner' or group of related tasks. They share common initialization needs
  config:
    repo: ci-repo  # Configuration parameters can be set at runner level and overriden by nested tasks/steps
  tasks:  # List of tasks provided by this runner. We can run one task at a time
    publish:
      config: # Tasks can have configuration parameters
        properties:
          moo: maa
          shoo: shaa
      steps:
        - publish:
            path: org/path
    promote:
      steps:  # Tasks can have many steps that will run sequentially
        - promote:
            repo: promotion-repo
        - send_email:
            recipient: group@mycompany.com
buildcxx:  # Another runner
  tasks:
    debug:
      steps:
        - clean_build_folders
        - cmake:
            cmake_args: -DFoo=Bar
...
```

The entry point of my package, `bsf.py`, accepts 2 arguments:

```
> ./bsf.py RUNNER TASK
```

For example, with the above `tasks.yml`:

```
> ./bsf.py release promote
```

This will run all the steps in the `promote` task of the `release` runner.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""bsf.py"""

from argparse import ArgumentParser
import yaml
import sys
import importlib
from runners import *  # Need to import all runners


def parse_arguments():
    mainparser = ArgumentParser('BSF')
    mainparser.add_argument('runner', help='Runner as specified in tasks.yml')
    mainparser.add_argument('task', help='Task to run as specified in tasks.yml')
    mainparser.add_argument('-s', '--source', default='source', help='Location of source to be build')
    return mainparser.parse_args()


def get_config(cfg):
    with open(cfg, 'r') as stream:
        return yaml.load(stream)


def get_runner_class(runner, module='runners'):
    """
    Returns the runner class specified byt the runner name
    :param runner: string with runner class name
    :param module: module where to search for runner classes
    :return: runner class
    """
    runners = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[module], inspect.isclass)  # Returns classes in module
    runner_list = dict()
    for rn in runners:
        runner_class_name, runner_class_object = rn
        runner_name = str(runner_class_name.lower())  # Convert class name to lowercase, maybe better to use a class prop
        # dict with lower case task name and proper class name capitalization
        runner_list[runner_name] = runner_class_name
    return getattr(importlib.import_module(module), runner_list[runner])


def get_resulting_task_config(default_tasks, runner_config, task_config):
    """
    Returns the  resulting by overriding:
    - default is overriden by runner
    - runner is overriden by task
    :param default_tasks: global tasks definition and config
    :param runner_config: current runner config
    :param task_config: current task config
    :return: dictionary containing the resulting config
    """
    resulting_config = default_tasks
    resulting_config.update(runner_config)
    resulting_config.update(task_config)
    return resulting_config


def main():
    args = parse_arguments()
    runner = args.runner
    task = args.task
    default_tasks = get_config('tasks.yml')

    print 'Running %s:%s' % (runner, task)

    runner_config = dict()
    task_config = dict()

    if runner not in default_tasks:
        print 'ERROR: runner not defined in tasks'
        sys.exit(-1)
    if task not in default_tasks[runner]['tasks']:
        print 'ERROR task %s not defined in runner %s' % (task, runner)
        sys.exit(-1)

    task_definition = {tsk: default_tasks[runner]['tasks'][tsk] for tsk in default_tasks[runner]['tasks'] if tsk == task}

    if 'config' in default_tasks[runner]:
        runner_config = default_tasks[runner]['config']

    if 'config' in default_tasks[runner]['tasks'][task]:
        task_config = default_tasks[runner]['tasks'][task]['config']

    runner_class = get_runner_class(runner)
    rnr = runner_class(args.source, task_definition, runner_config, task_config)
    rnr.do(task)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the `pipeline.py` file, with different classes extending a base one.

The reason for extending the base class is we may not always need all components: for example, running a `build` task will not need the 'artifact repository manager' needed by the `publish` and `promote` tasks. This will allow us to use just the parts of the framework that we need at a given time.

```
"""pipeline.py: Pipeline classes
We have a basic pipeline class with the minimum config.
Additional classes extend the functionality and initialize different parts as needed
This allows to just initialize the required parts and group related methods together
"""

import os
import sys


class Pipeline(object):
    """Base pipeline class, in charge of the minimal configuration
    """
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source  #: Source code folder
        self.build_number = os.environ.get('bamboo_buildNumber')
        self.vcs = None  #: Version control manager
        self.binary_repo = None  #: Binary repository manager, ie: Artifactory
        self.confluence_client = None  #: Confluence API client

        self._build_version = None

    def init_vcs(self):
        """Initialize VCS manager from environment and/or info from source folder
        """
        self.vcs = 'Foo'

    @ property
    def build_version(self):
        if self._build_version is None:
            self._build_version = os.environ.get('bamboo_build_version')
            if self._build_version is None:
                """Ideally will try to get the version by other means"""
                print "ERROR: Can't determine the build version"
                sys.exit(-1)
        return self._build_version


class ReleaseWorker(Pipeline):
    """Extends the Pipeline with release tasks
    """
    def __init__(self, source):
        super(ReleaseWorker, self).__init__(source)

    def publish(self, path, repo):
        print 'ReleaseWorker: Publishing to %s in %s' % (path, repo)
        # self.pipeline.binary_repo.publish(path, repo)

    def promote(self, repo):
        print 'ReleaseWorker: Promoting to %s' % repo
        # self.pipeline.binary_repo.promote(repo)

    def send_email(self, recipient):
        print 'Sending email to %s' % recipient
```

And finally, this is the `runner.py` file. Each runner has a different `configure` method and shares a common `do` method. The generic `do` iterates through the steps (that are methods in the corresponding pipeline worker class) running them.

```
from pipeline import ReleaseWorker

import inspect


def _parse_step_config(step):
    # Apply step specific step_config. Defaults are defined in step method level
    if type(step) is dict:           # Step contains additional config
        step_name = step.keys()[0]   # Steps should be a dict with one single item
        step_config = step[step_name]
    else:
        step_name = step
        step_config = dict()
    return step_name, step_config


class Runner(object):
    """Base runner class"""
    def __init__(self, source, task_definition, runner_config, task_config):
        self.source = source
        self.config = runner_config
        self.config.update(task_config)
        self.task = task_definition
        self.pipeline = None  # Should be initialized by the child class

    def configure(self):
        """Configuration should be done at child level"""
        pass

    def do(self, task):
        """Ideally, child classes should not override this method"""
        self.configure()
        steps = self.task[task]['steps']
        for step in steps:
            print('-'*120 + '\nRunning step %s' % step)
            step_name, step_config = _parse_step_config(step)

            step_method = getattr(self.pipeline, step_name)        # Get the method
            valid_args = inspect.getargspec(step_method).args[1:]  # See what arguments from task config are applicable
            print valid_args
            # Compute step config
            step_resulting_config = self.config
            step_resulting_config.update(step_config)

            step_arguments = {arg: (step_resulting_config[arg])
                              for arg in valid_args
                              if arg in step_resulting_config}  # Dict with applicable args

            step_method(**step_arguments)  # Run step


class Release(Runner):

    def configure(self):
        self.pipeline = ReleaseWorker(source=self.source)
        self.pipeline.binary_repo = 'Foo'  # This should be an object from some manager class
```

In case you want to get this files, you can save all the copy/paste by cloning [this repo](https://github.com/cattz/simple_bsf). I hope no one gets upset for me adding that link.

I have several concern with this:

- I have the feeling I'm overcomplicating things
- I have a horrible naming patter there:

  - runner = group of tasks
  - pipeline = build (substantive, as in 'my build is broken')

In case you are interested in the *real* project, you can follow the development [here](https://github.com/cattz/build_scripts_framework)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to simplify the `get_runner_class` method.

First step is to add a class attribute `name` to each runner, so we don't have to rely on the class name to match the yaml file key.

New `Runner` class:

```
class Relase(Runner):
    name = 'release'
...
```

The other simplification is to use `Runner.__subclasses__()` to get the list of all possible runners.

New `get_runner_class` method (much cleaner and explicit)

```
def get_runner_class(runner):
    runners = Runner.__subclasses__()
    for rn in runners:
         if rn.name == runner:
            return rn
    return None
```